# How to make a dynamically moving View float on top of a ViewGroup?

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I'm currently using a library that allows me to move freely a CardView in my screen, based on the user's finger. Here's my problem: I have a view Group on top that needs to stay below that CardView, but I'm not managing to do so.

I've tried using Frame Layout, but it didn't work as planned. The best I could do [was that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuNd2.png)

but still, not what I meant to dO (card view completely floating around the "toolbar")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/framelayout"
android:background="@color/verdeClaro"
tools:context=".View.Activity.LeitorMbookActivity"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
>

  <com.wenchao.cardstack.CardStack
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:id="@+id/cardStackContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding = "20dp"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    />

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"

        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/home_icon"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        >

        <com.akexorcist.roundcornerprogressbar.RoundCornerProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_height="6dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            app:rcProgressColor="@color/white"
            app:rcBackgroundColor="@color/verde_musgo"
            app:rcRadius="2dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>




</FrameLayout>
```

The library I'm using to move the card is [that](https://github.com/wenchaojiang/AndroidSwipeableCardStack).

Comment: did you try to move your `CardStack` at the bottom of your XML Layout file? (just before `</FrameLayout>`

Comment: Yes, it was actually on the bottom the first time

Comment: because in a `FrameLayout`, the `z-index` is defined by the order in which the items are added.

Comment: Changed back to what you said, but still didn't work :/

Comment: maybe you can try `setZ()` : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setZ(float)

Comment: Maybe I'll have to override some methods to override the children of the stack( there is a stack of card views). (And change the z atritubte)